# Size of widget in Gtk.Grid

Tags: python, gtk, python-3.4

I'm trying to arrange multiple Gtk.Entry in a 9x9 Gtk.Grid. I have set the size of entries with `width_chars=1` (yes, I want them small). The problem is that the grid doesn't respect the entry's size and expands it. I tried it using a Gtk.Box instead of Grid (I couldn't arrange it in 9x9) and it did render the entries of 1 width. Program is in python3. Here is my code, what am I doing wrong?

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
wind=Gtk.Window(title='My App')
wind.connect('delete-event',Gtk.main_quit)
grid=Gtk.Grid()
wind.add(grid)
s=[[0 for x in range(9)] for x in range(9)]
for i,j in [(x,y) for x in range(9) for y in range(9)]:
     s[i][j]=Gtk.Entry(width_chars=1,xalign=0.5,text='0')
     grid.attach(s[i][j],j,i,1,1)
wind.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

This outputs this: [Program output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Be2jB.jpg)

Edit2: After adding this question, I came to know that the grid inherits the 'expand' property from its children. So I have tried setting the `halign` and `hexpand` properties of the entries to `False`, but it still produces the same result.
I also read about Glade and decided to try to create the same layout through it. But it still produces the same output. Is there no way to stop the widgets / grid / window from expanding like that?

Edit3: I was on ubuntu gnome 15.10 when I originally asked and answered this question. Right now I am on regular ubuntu 14.04 and I noticed something interesting. I tried the same program and this time it turned out that I didn't need either of the above mentioned commands to make it work. It would be very helpful if someone explained why does that happen.

Comment: When you add a widget to a GtkWindow, the widget will occupy the *entirety* of the GtkWindow's space, as there's nothing else controlling its size. So the GtkGrid will stretch to be the size of the GtkWindow, and thus your GtkEntries stretch horizontally. Using a GtkBox works because the GtkGrid itself isn't set to take all the space the GtkBox has available for it, so the GtkBox will give the GtkGrid its "preferred" size and no more. For your situation, I'm not sure what the solution is, but it would involve not being able to resize the GtkWindow if there aren't going to be any more controls.

Comment: @andlabs That's not it. What I meant was using a GtkBox **instead of** GtkGrid works. I didn't mean that placing a GtkGrid **inside** a GtkBox works. I will edit the question and make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out to be setting a default size for the window and setting its `hexpand` value to `False`.

```
wind.set_default_size(200,200)
wind.set_hexpand(False)
```